# Reference to Observable with class injection

Tags: swift, mvvm, reactive-programming, rx-swift

Please consider the following structure:

```
class UpModel {
    var isThisRealLife: Variable<Bool>

    required init(model: UpperModel) {
        isThisRealLife = Variable(upperModel.isThisRealLife) //true
        testFlagChange()
    }

    private func testFlagChange() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            self.isThisRealLife = false
        }
    }
}
```

This model is instanced by the `UpperViewModel`, by injecting it's own `UpperModel` instance, something like this:

```
class UpperViewModel {
    init() {
        let upperModel = UpperModel()

        let upModel = UpModel(model: upperModel)
        let upViewModel = UpViewModel(model: upModel)
    }
}
```

Now I have my `UpViewModel` class:

```
class UpViewModel {
    let bag = DisposeBag()

    init(model: UpModel) {
        let upModelVariable = Variable(model)
        let lowViewModel = LowViewModel<LowModel>(model: upModelVariable)

        upModelVariable.asObservable().flatMap({ $0.isThisRealLife.asObservable() }).subscribe(onNext: { value in
            print("changed to \(value) -- at UpVM") //1
        }).disposed(by: bag)
    }
}
```

**1:**  reacts properly to the flag change after 3 seconds.

Ok, so far, so good.
But now I want to keep sending this `UpClass` reference down so other classes can react to changes on the `isThisRealLife` property.

So this is my `LowViewModel`, who receives the `UpModel` reference:

```
class LowViewModel<Model: LowModel> {
    let bag = DisposeBag()
    let lowModel: LowModel

    required init(model: Variable<UpModel>) {
        lowModel = Model(model: model.value) 

        model.asObservable().flatMap({ $0.isThisRealLife.asObservable() }).subscribe(onNext: { value in
            print("changed to \(value) -- at LowVM") //2
        }).disposed(by: bag)
    }
}
```

**2:** This does not react to the flag change.

And this is the `LowModel` but I'm not even using it just yet, since I seem to be losing reference to `isThisRealLife` property at the previous step:

```
class LowModel {
    var isThisRealLife: Observable<Bool>

    required init(model: UpModel) {
        isThisRealLife = model.isThisRealLife.asObservable
    }
}
```

**Notes**:

- I understand `Variable` is deprecated and I will refactor to `BehaviorRelay` as soon as I can make everything work.
- I tried to make the example as reduced as possible to illustrate the problem, but of course the issue might be in the grater scope -- in which case I will gladly provide more information as required.
- There are lots of Protocols involved to make things generic and reusable, so I removed all of them to try and focus on (at least what I think is) the issue. Also the GUI is not important right now, just the business logic.

---

Some more lengthy context in case anyone's interested:

Me and my team are working on a new architecture for our project. 
Since our design is fairly consistent, we're validating this concept of working with "components", which are a set of View, ViewModel and Model that can be reused throughout the app.

The main idea is that each screen is a set of MVVM with ViewController, ViewModel and Model, and they implement the "components" as needed. We're implementing Reactive to allow some components to react when there are certain changes in the "parent"/"upper" Model.

I've been working with reactive in RxSwift for almost a year now, but the project I worked on was fairly straightforward and the usage was repetitive, so my knowledge on the subject became narrow (which was my mistake, ofc).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you got confused with passing by value or reference to the init.

I am not sure what is your target of this design .. I could not understood properly but I guess your problem is ...

in #1 you created new local variable
let upModelVariable = Variable(model)

in 2# you registered a func parameter as observable but it dies by the return of the init beacuse it is passed by value (try inout)

That's why #1 works and #2 not.

Try to use inout for passing reference like this [See if it works as you wanted]

```
    init(model: UpModel) {
            var upModelVariable = Variable(model)
            let _ = LowViewModel<LowModel>(model: &upModelVariable)

            upModelVariable.asObservable().flatMap({ $0.isThisRealLife.asObservable() }).subscribe(onNext: { value in
                print("changed to \(value) -- at UpVM") //1
            }).disposed(by: bag)
        } 
class LowViewModel<Model: LowModel> {
    let bag = DisposeBag()
    let lowModel: LowModel
    required init( model: inout Variable<UpModel>) {
        lowModel = Model(model: model.value)

        model.asObservable().flatMap({ $0.isThisRealLife.asObservable() }).subscribe(onNext: { value in
            print("changed to \(value) -- at LowVM") //2
        }).disposed(by: bag)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nour, thanks for your answer. I implemented your suggestion and now #2 prints the first emitted value (true). Unfortunately, after the async call, only #1 receives the flagChange event (false).
Do you have any insights on why the LowViewModel seems to be unsubscribing early to the Variable?

Comment: probably because upModelVariable is local variable initialized inside  init(model: UpModel).. you can not keep the reference to it..   try to make it class variable and try again... or pass isThisRealLife from the origin as reference (inout)  .. code is bit confusing for me